# Error upon Expression.Lambda().Compile()

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I have the following simple code:

```
  var b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "b");
  var negativeB = Expression.Negate(b);
```

If I stop there and try to quick watch `Expression.Lambda(negativeB).Compile()` I get an error:

> variable 'b' of type 'System.Double' referenced from scope '', but it
>   is not defined

The other answers about this error message don't seem to address what's going on here, or how to fix it in this case.

Comment: You should use Lambda<Func<double, double>> to make it strongly typed. Things like DynamicInvoke are orders of magnitude slower than strongly typed alternatives.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek, I don't know what formula the user will type in. Can I create `Lambda<Func<?, ?, ...>>` at runtime so I can use `Invoke()` instead of `DynamicInvoke()`?

Comment: If you do not know, then there is no help. From the example it seemed to me that you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an expression `negativeB` that requires an input parameter of `b`. However when you are defining your Lambda you are not defining any parameters.

What you need to do is this:

```
Expression.Lambda(negativeB, b).Compile();
```

This then compiles

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the parameter (`b`) in the Lambda:

```
var l = Expression.Lambda(negativeB, b).Compile();
var r = l.DynamicInvoke(32); // = -32
```